# Parallax scrolling with UIPanGestureRecognizer swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, parallax, uipangesturerecognizer

I have got two images for a game I want to parallax scroll by panning using sprite kit.

The foreground image is 1.25 x larger than the background image, I'm using UIPanGestureRecognizer to pan the images. So I'm multiplying the translation of the foreground by 1.25 (foregroundMoveModifier) so that the player pans to the edge of both images at the same time. (hope that makes sense)

I have a physics edge for each of the images so that they cannot pan off the edge of the view.

But the background image is reaching the edge and being stopped before the foreground is, so for a second or two the background is still and the foreground is still moving, which ruins the illusion of depth that the parallax scrolling creates. It seems as though the foreground translation needs to be multiplied by higher than 1.25 so it pans at a faster rate?

Have I over simplified this in my head and it isn't as simple as multiplying the foreground translation by 1.25?

```
func panned(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began{

        }else{
            if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed{

                var translation = sender.translationInView(sender.view)
                translation = CGPointMake(-translation.x, translation.y);

                background.position = CGPointMake(background.position.x - translation.x, background.position.y - translation.y)
                foreground.position = CGPointMake(foreground.position.x - translation.x*foregroundMoveModifier , foreground.position.y - translation.y*foregroundMoveModifier)



                sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: sender.view)

            } else {
                if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended{

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: wouldn't you need to pan the background at the 1.25x rate, not the foreground,  the background is the smaller image, so it has to move farther to keep up with the foreground